# variable Transformation function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which takes variable & dataframe as inputs and then creates 19 
transformed variables.

When i run it, i am not getting any error but at the same time new variables are not getting created.

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

```
function(v,d) {
  attach(d)
  d$v1 <- log(v)
  d$v2 <- exp(v)
  d$v3 <- sqrt(v)
  d$v4 <- (v)^0.3333
  d$v5 <- (v)^2
  d$v6 <- (v)^3
  d$v7 <- sin(v)
  d$v8 <- cos(v)
  d$v9 <- tan(v)
  d$v10 <- 1/(v) 
  d$v11 <- 1/log(v)
  d$v12 <- 1/exp(v)
  d$v13 <- 1/sqrt(v)
  d$v14 <- 1/(v^0.3333)
  d$v15 <- 1/(v^2)
  d$v16 <- 1/(v^3) 
  d$v17 <- 1/sin(v)
  d$v18 <- 1/cos(v)
  d$v19 <- 1/tan(v)
}
```

Comment: You don't have a return statement in your function, so the function returns `1/tan(v)`.

Comment: I've seen minified javascript before but this is my first time seeing minified R..

Comment: Perhaps `within` or `transform` is useful here, to avoid all the `d$`? See examples on the help pages.

Comment: I've "unminified" your code so that it's a little easier to read

Comment: How have you got to the point of creating a function that tries to create 19 variables without noticing it wouldn't work even if you were creating one variable? Start small. Small is easier to debug. That your example is 19 variables is irrelevant.

Comment: I was trying to understand creation & storage of variables in a function. I should have tried with one variable as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your question, but see comments afterwards:

```
trans = function(v) {
  ## Add in your other 15 variables ...
  d = data.frame(log(v), exp(v), sqrt(v), v^0.3333)
  colnames(d) =paste0("v", 1:ncol(d))
  return(d)
}
trans(runif(10))
```

1. Notice that I'm not passing in `d` since I strongly suspect that your are creating an empty data frame for use in the function. If this is not the case, then pass in `d` and have something like

   ```
   ##D is the original data frame
   D[, 1:ncol(d)] = d
   ```
2. Since all columns are numeric, a matrix may be better here.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! What i was trying to do is create transformed variables for all the columns of the data frame & store these new variables also in the original data frame. The purpose is to use all these in regression modeling.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do regression with lots of variable transformations to create flexible effect shapes. There are packages for something called "Fractional Polynomial" models that do just that, maybe that's better than trying to code up your own: [mfp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mfp/) and [bfp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bfp). In my experience, it tends to work even better to use semi-parametric regression with penalized splines if you need flexible effect shapes, the best pkg for that: [mgcv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/)

Answer (score 0):

R function are what's known as immutable meaning that they don't change parameters that are passed in. They only work on a copy.

So you need to return the new data frame or it won't "stick".

```
myfunction = function(v, d) {
  d$v1 <- log(d[v])
  d$v2 <- exp(d[v])
  d$v3 <- sqrt(d[v])
  d$v4 <- (d[v])^0.3333
  d$v5 <- (d[v])^2
  d$v6 <- (d[v])^3
  d$v7 <- sin(d[v])
  d$v8 <- cos(d[v])
  d$v9 <- tan(d[v])
  d$v10 <- 1/(d[v]) 
  d$v11 <- 1/log(d[v])
  d$v12 <- 1/exp(d[v])
  d$v13 <- 1/sqrt(d[v])
  d$v14 <- 1/(d[v]^0.3333)
  d$v15 <- 1/(d[v]^2)
  d$v16 <- 1/(d[v]^3) 
  d$v17 <- 1/sin(d[v])
  d$v18 <- 1/cos(d[v])
  d$v19 <- 1/tan(d[v])
  return(d) # it must be returned, or the changes won't be applied
}

d = myfunction(d)
```